# save array values and pass it to the next page

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have an array in homePage ts and view it to html as well but I need when the user clicks on them passing this data to another page

```
adsProfile() {
  this.navCtrl.push(AdsProfilePage, {Name :this.name,Address:this.address});
}
```

I need to use this values in ads Profile Page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `AdsProfilePage` you have to write:

```
name:string;
address:string;

constructor(public navParams: NavParams) {
   this.name = navParams.data.Name;
   this.address = navParams.data.Address;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess there is some change to the answer given by Durga Sriram.

In AdsProfilePage, it could be written

```
name: string;
address: string;

constructor(public navParams: NavParams) {
   this.name = navParams.get('Name');
   this.address = navParams.get('Address');
}
```

I guess it would also work fine.